# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint error JPA spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables notification and message.

Message.java

```
...
...
@Table(name = "message",        
 uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueMessage",
 columnNames = { "message_id" })}) 
public class Message implements Serializable {

@Id 
@Column(name = “message_id")
private int messageId;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "start_time")
private Date startTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "end_time")
private Date endTime;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void generateMessageId(){
    this.messageId = Math.abs(Objects.hash(this.getDescription(),
            this.getStartTime().getTime() / 1000));
}
```

My use case is -- I will be creating a message with certain description and start time. If I get same message again, I should be able to update the endTime. MessageId is calculated separately under method generateMessageId as this will act as an identifier to find if message has already been saved. If yes, I will update the message. It works well for first message but when I try to save again with updated endTime, I get

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint “message_pkey”

Steps:
I tried:

```
Message m1 = new Message();
m1.setDescription(“fake”);
m1.setStartTime(“2022-01-03T12:05:00”)

messageRepository.save(m1);

This works well. I can see a row in database with

Message_id      description     start_time      end_time
46536723        fake            2022-01-03T12:05:00     null


Message m2 = new Message();
m2.setDescription(“fake”);
m2.setStartTime(“2022-01-03T12:05:00”);
m2.setEndTime(“2022-01-05T12:00:00)

messageRepository.save(m2);
```

I get ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint error.
Isn’t jpa should find the existing id and do an update to the row instead of inserting?

Please suggest if this method looks like a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the message endTime, First time, it works because there is no entry of that message now when you are trying to update but you are not setting the id by default id is zero and if Id is zero it will try to save the message instead of updating.

For resolving this issue you can check (by finding the message by message because the message is unique) if that message is present then update the endTime.

Comment: I am using method generateMessageId() to update my message_id.  Message_id should be unique overall. And since it is unique, jpa should had updated the row. I am confused here.

Comment: When you are calling the same method somehow (in your code) it is not getting updated it is getting inserted. once try that approach maybe it will.